# How to click on each name through xpath on the website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to use the `driver.find_element_by_xpath`in selenium to click on each of the names listed in this [page](https://www.dechert.com/content/dechert/en/people.html#firstName=&lastInitial=&lastName=&office=Philadelphia&page=1&q=&school=Villanova+University)

I have the following piece of code which is used as an example for just clicking on a single persons name

```
python_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="search_results_people_search_832248975"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/h3""")
python_button.click()
```

however when I run this it states

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <h3 data-bind="text: personDispNm">...</h3> is not clickable at point (387, 558). Other element would receive the click: <div>...</div>
```

How do I get around this issue

Comment: You need to scroll to the element first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on each name through xpath on the website `https://www.dechert.com/content/dechert/en/people.html#firstName=&lastInitial=&lastName=&office=Philadelphia&page=1&q=&school=Villanova+University` you need to wait for the *names* to be visible and then collect the *href* attributes to traverse sequencially as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  hrefs= []
  base_url = "https://www.dechert.com/content/dechert/en/people.html#firstName=&lastInitial=&lastName=&office=Philadelphia&page=1&q=&school=Villanova+University" 
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get(base_url)
  persons = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='name']//a[contains(@href,'/people/')]")))
  for person in persons:
      hrefs.append(person.get_attribute("href"))
  for href in hrefs:
      driver.get(href)
      print(driver.current_url)
      driver.get(base_url)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  https://www.dechert.com/people/b/april-banko.html
  https://www.dechert.com/people/c/nicholas-carroll.html
  https://www.dechert.com/people/e/william-elder.html
  https://www.dechert.com/people/g/joe-gribbin.html
  https://www.dechert.com/people/t/joseph-tate.html
  https://www.dechert.com/people/t/marissa-tribuiani.html
  ```
- Perhaps you can also use @Andersson's solution which was near perfect with certain modification as follows:

  ```
  links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='name']//a[contains(@href,'/people/')]")))]
  for link in links:
      driver.get(link)
      print(driver.current_url)
      driver.get(base_url)
  ```

Comment: Why do you think that adding ExplicitWait makes my already working solution *"perfect"*?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking I would get the list oh hyper-references and then navigate to each page:

```
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[h3]')]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # Do something on the page
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, can you update the xpath as following:

```
python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//*[@id='search_results_people_search_832248975']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a/h3")
python_button.click()
```

Comment: This will work for first link only while OP wants to click all links!

Comment: Yes, @Andersson This will work only for first link. But since he is not even able to click on first link, this would be helpful. And for selecting all the links he can find elements and iterate over as you rightly suggested.